# Can the NADPH/NADP+ ratio affect the FMN to FMNH2 ratio in the complex I of the mitochondria?

Tags: mitochondria, bioenergetics

This is the reaction:

FMNH2 + NAD(P)+ <-> FMN + NAD(P)H + H+

The reaction works either with NADH/NAD+ or NADPH/NADP+

I know that the NADH/NAD+ ratio affects the FMN to FMNH2 ratio
But does the NADPH/NADP+ ratio affect the FMN to FMNH2 ratio in the complex I of the mitochondria?

Comment: No, because FMN is bound to the complex covalently.

Comment: @SciEnt — if you are going to answer questions please do so as an answer not as a comment. When you click on the comment link this is made quite explicit. Ignoring this injunction undermines the way Stack Exchange operates.